# From where does this - ve sign come from

Tags: mathematical-physics

Let
θ=54
5θ=270
2θ+3θ=270
2θ=270-3θ
sin(2θ)=sin(270-3θ)
sin(2θ)= -cos(3θ)
From where does -ve sign come from?

270-3θ will be in 2quad where sin is +ve.

Comment: "-ve"? "+ve"? What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer "-ve" and "+ve" are shorthands for "negative" and "positive", respectively.

Comment: Huh; never seen that before and nothing came up when I Googled it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sin (270^\circ-\alpha) &= \sin(270^\circ)\cos(\alpha) -\cos(270^\circ) \sin(\alpha) \\
&=- \cos (\alpha)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(-90^\circ -\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha$